# Exception information: Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a code here that, has to search and post back information selected in a table above the add button, the search works but im having a problem with the post back to the table function. These are the lines it shows to have errors.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\application\models\ServiceProviders.php(68): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))

```
public function getName($id)
{
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->where('service_provider_id = ?', $id);

    $result = $this->fetchRow($select);  //this line
    return $result['service_provider_name']; 
}
```

> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\application\modules\admin\controllers\AjaxController.php(1104): Model_ServiceProviders->getName(NULL)

```
    public function postserviceproviderAction()

        {
            $form = new Form_IndustrialTable();       
            $this->view->form = $form;

            if(!$form->isValid($_POST)) 
            {
                 $values=$form->getValues();
            }

            $sp = $this->getRequest()->getPost('serviceprovider', null);


            $mdlserviceprovider = new Model_ServiceProviders();
            $serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($id); //this line


            $rtn_array= array(  'sp'    => $sp,                         
                                'serviceprovider ' => $serviceprovider);         


             $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
             $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

            echo Zend_Json::encode($rtn_array);

}
```

Comment: Try something like `$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow('service_provider_id = ' . $id);`

Comment: Im getting a fatal error of; Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_ServiceProviders::getmodel() in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\application\models\ServiceProviders.php on line 68  same line

Comment: Im not using a Dbtable instead a model folder

Comment: It was an example, try : $this->fetchRow('service_provider_id = ' . $id);

Comment: try var_dump($mdlserviceprovider).

Comment: Thanks that helped no more geting errors,its just returning null and not appearing in my table but will work through it. In my network here is my html null

{"sp":null,"serviceprovider ":null} and response <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>{"sp":null,"serviceprovider ":null}

Answer (score 0):

You don't put any initial value to `$id` so it's `null` which causes error.

You want SQL query to look something like `SELECT * FROM service_providers WHERE service_provider_id = 50`, but for this you have to provide id which you want to find (50 in this example). You need to add some value to variable `$id` before using in `$select->where('service_provider_id = ?', $id);`, but your code you never put any value to variable `$id`.

If I'm guessing your idea then you need to change line:

```
$serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($id);
```

to:

```
$serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($sp);
```

Also this part of your code probably unnecessary as it does nothing:

```
        $form = new Form_IndustrialTable();       
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if(!$form->isValid($_POST)) 
        {
             $values=$form->getValues(); //you never use $values
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say an initial value?